# Swift 3: Only continue processing Dictionary value if it's of type Array

Tags: swift

I am receiving a data structure over the wire that's of type `[String: AnyObject]`. The reason for `AnyObject` is simply because the value can be of type `Array` or `Dictionary`. My condition is straight forward:

```
if let data = list["foo"], data.count > 0 {
  // do stuff
}
```

My problem is, I only want that condition to pass if `data` is an `Array`. The condition I have fails because `count` property seems to work on a `Dictionary` as well (It probably counts the number of keys in the dictionary).

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Sorry, but not clear to me why your code compiles at all — is `data` an `AnyObject`?  If so, where `count` comes from?

Comment: What type of Arrays are they? What type are the elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast `data` as an Array in your if statement:

```
if let data = list["foo"] as? [Any], data.count > 0 {
  // do stuff
}
```

This will make sure that `data` is an Array before doing any operations on it.

Comment: `[Any]` means an `Array` of `Any` elements.